# compute array of correlations between two multidimensional arrays in R

Tags: arrays, r, apply

I have two three-dimensional arrays X[nx, ny, nt] and Y[nx, ny, nt]. I want to compute a correlation matrix R such that Rij = cor(Xij, Yij).

I can do this via nested for loops:

```
for (i in 1:nx) {
  for (j in 1:ny) {
    R[i,j] <- cor(X[i,j,], Y[i,j,], use='complete.obs')
  }
}
```

Is there a better way using some variant of apply?

Comment: `R <- sapply(1:nx, function(i,j) cor(X[i,j,], Y[i,j,], use='complete.obs'), 1:ny)`?

Comment: If you are concern about the speed, the cor function gives much more slowness then the use of for

Comment: @Parfait That result has dimension [nt*nt, nx].

Comment: @Gilgamesh You are correct. My original for loop is faster than the apply with abind below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `abind` we may combine these two arrays into a four-dimensional one and then employ `apply` across the first two dimensions:

```
library(abind)
apply(abind(X, Y, along = 4), 1:2, function(Z) cor(Z[, 1], Z[, 2]))
```